# Scala - add type definition to declaration - keyboard shortcut

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

Is there a keyboard shortcut for [adding](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Working+with+Scala+Show+Type+Info+Action?replyToComment=58658828&#comment-58658828) type definitions to Scala declarations in IntelliJ ? I cannot find any. I can find the tooltip though, but a shortcut would be nicer.

Comment: go to the declaration and do `ALT + ENTER`

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately, no. The best option is as @pamu explained. Move your cursor to the variable or function declaration, type ALT+ENTER, and select "Add type annotation to definition" in the menu. You can still avoid the mouse by navigating with the down arrow and selecting with enter.

[image]

Comment: Right, thanks, I guess this is the closest thing to a direct shortcut , right ? This of course easy enough, but there is no direct shortcut ? I was wondering.

Comment: It is also possible to display the type from the menu (View -> Type Info) which can also be mapped to a shortcut key via the Preferences -> Keymap dialog. This doesn't help with adding the type info to the code but it helps when you just want to find out what the inferred type is.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I recently came across another way of doing this (at least with IntelliJ 2020.2 and Scala plugin 4.42):  Select the method name, press Ctrl+F6 (Refactor/Change Signature...), select checkbox "Specify result type" (or change Settings to make this the default), and complete the Refactor operation.

For fields and variables I've been using Ctrl-Alt-F and Ctrl-Alt-V (Refactor/Extract/Introduce/Field and Refactor/Extract/Introduce/Variable, respectively) in a similar way for a while now.  The main difference is that in this case an expression needs to be selected (instead of a field or variable name).  The best is to type the expression and then introduce the field or variable in this way.